# Passing template to "rails new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When calling "rails new" it is obviously possible to pass some kind of template or setup script via the "-m" command line parameter. I found this via https://github.com/fortuity/rails3-mongoid-devise/wiki/Tutorial-(Walkthrough). And https://github.com/fortuity/rails3-application-templates/blob/master/rails3-mongoid-devise-template.rb looks like DSL for manipulating Rails applications. That looks quite cool, but I was not able to find more information about it. Could somebody point me to the related documentation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is some information you may find useful:

- [Rails templates](http://m.onkey.org/rails-templates) (a high-level overview)
- [Templates in Rails 3](http://neovintage.blogspot.com/2010/04/templates-in-rails-3.html) (lists some of the commands and links to documentation)
- [RDoc for Thor::Actions](http://rdoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor/Actions)
- [Source for Rails specific actions](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/actions.rb)

I also found [this guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) in the Rails source code which isn't linked to from the main Guides page, but may have some useful information for you.

You may also be interested in the [source for the default app template methods](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb), which is used when you use `rails new` with no `-m` option, or [this application template](https://gist.github.com/708939) I started on a while back that explores some different options.

Comment: Wow! That's everything I was looking for and one more reason to invest more time in learning Rais! :-)