# How create custom app on Rails and auto initiate tedious setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails.

Every time, when I want to create a new app,
I should add in bootstrap, simple-form, devise, and many gems, create some tables, etc. 
For example , I write my own css file , how to copy the default file in every new app project.

It's a tedious routine.

Is there any tutorial, or keywords for searching, what I want to learn?

Comment: You can pass a `-m TEMPLATE` option to `rails new` where `TEMPLATE` is a Ruby file. You can check out the following question's answer for lots more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058090/passing-template-to-rails-new

Comment: This question format is whiny, which inhibits getting answers; but the underlying question is OK.  Remember that if you think this is tough, It is barely even the beginning of *professional software engineer*

Comment: @Deefour you comment should be 'answerized'. :)

Comment: @HasanIqbalAnik Maybe so, but all I'm really doing is linking to another question/answer, and link-only answers are generally a no-no here *(I think this question should just be closed out as a duplicate)*.

Answer (score 1):

@Deefour covers the main solution - the only thing I thought I might add is that you might like [Rails Composer](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-composer/) - it's handy for any situation where you create a lot of Rails apps, particularly because it can help resolve gem dependencies. (Would comment, but insufficient rep currently.)